# What's the difference between the two map implementation, one uses list comprehension and other uses the recursion?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I just got into Haskell, I've been going through the book "Learn you a Haskell" from the website. right now I am in the Higher Order functions chapter.

The author talked about implementing a custom map function. I thought to implement it with the little knowledge I had and then compare it with author. I used the list comprehension and the author used the recursion. Same as the standard library

```
-- me
map1 :: (t -> a) -> [t] -> [a]
map1 f xs = [f x | x<-xs]

-- author
map2 :: (t -> a) -> [t] -> [a]
map2 _ [] = []
map2 f (x:xs) = f x : map2 f xs
```

Why is recursion chosen above list comprehension? is it more performant ?

just want to know why the things are the way they are?

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing particularly deep going on here. The two implementations should be essentially identical in any reasonable Haskell implementation.

The version that uses recursion and pattern matching does have a few things going for it, though.

1. It uses "more primitive" parts of the language. In fact, it would be very reasonable for a Haskell implementation to internally convert list comprehensions into calls to `map` and other similar functions, or into a directly recursive definition.
2. It is more generalizable. There is no list-comprehension-like syntax sugar for other data types like trees, arrays, sets, dictionaries, etc. in standard Haskell 2010. But pattern matching is available for a wide variety of common types, and recursion is useful all over the place.
3. It is good pedagogy. Recursion especially can be unfamiliar to some folks coming from an imperative background. Additionally, the implementation that uses recursion passes its function argument along to another function call, making non-trivial use of the fact that Haskell supports functions as first-class objects. Some languages do not support that cleanly, so seeing, using, and playing with that feature can be a stumbling block for some.

Comment: "There is no list-comprehension-like syntax sugar for other data types like trees, arrays, sets, dictionaries, etc." [_um actually_,](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/monad_comprehensions.html)

Comment: Regarding Point 1, see [section 3.11 of the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) for one suggested conversion of a list comprehension to a call to `concatMap`.